# 'lost' windows partition. how to get it going again?

Tags: windows-7, partition-recovery, disk-management, partition-magic

I was shrinking my partitions using Disk Management and it all went fine. Then I started PartitionMagic and it was saying me something like you have errors in the partitions (something like partition starting points in the hd) and do you want to fix them? I said yes and after that it got all screwed up. Now my 58.6 GB partition doesn't have a drive name. It has my ubuntu installation and I need it back desperately! How do I fix this issue? I tried partition recovery wizard in EaseUS but it didn't find any partitions to repair. But still shows the volume name and I can even browse inside the partition through it. I have attached images. I am really stuck.[image]

[image]

Comment: Does Windows boot normally? If so, good. You may need to boot to the Ubuntu LiveCD, backup your personal files from your Ubuntu partitions and then re-install. You could also try a GRUB repair.

Comment: I am not sure but first you can assign a drive letter to **ubuntu partition** then use grub repair using ubuntu live cd. it may work.

Comment: I installed ubuntu through wubi. The strange thing is I could still log into my ubuntu so which means the 'lost' partition is intact there. Only thing is I can't see it from Windows. Why is that?